# Problem with \emph in frame title when is used in beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I want to provide my students with slides in book format and I use `beamerarticle`. In my book format, `frametitles` are converted to `marginpars`. And because I write in catalan, all english words are `\emph`-asized.

I know that `\emph` or `$` (math environments) in frame titles have to be `\protect`-ed, so I use `\protect\emph{...}`. But this format doesn't work when the title is converted into a margin paragraph.

Next it's a non working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\mode<article>{%
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \marginpar{%
    \if\insertframetitle\empty\relax      
    \else
      \insertframetitle\newline%
    \fi
    \scriptsize\insertframesubtitle}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{\protect\emph{This title is a problem}}

%\begin{frame}{This title is not a problem}

Some text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It stops with next error message:

```
! Use of \@xmpar doesn't match its definition.
\beamer@ifnextcharospec #1#2->\def \reserved@a {
                                                #1}\def \reserved@b {#2}\fut...
l.17
```

If the special `frametitle` format for article is commented out or `\emph` is not used in titles, the problem disappears. Could you explain me what's wrong?

Comment: if you add another set of `{}` around `\protect\emph{...}` it compiles (but I'm not sure that is the output you want).

Comment: I think it is expanded more than once. Does `\begin{frame}{\protect\noexpand\protect\emph{This title is a problem}}` help?

Comment: `\if\insertframetitle\empty` is amost certainly not doing what you think it's doing. If it is non empty it tests if the first two tokens are the same letter, if it is empty it tests that `\relax` and the first token of `\newline` are both commands

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\if\insertframetitle\empty\relax
```

should be

```
\ifx\insertframetitle\empty\relax
```

If the intention is to test if the definition of `\insertframetitle` is the same as that of `\empty`. With this change the example runs without error.